# 'Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred'

Tags: swift, generics

I don't know why this happening, I'd like to return a parameter in accordance to MyProtocol with an array, so I'm trying to achieve that the following way:

```
import Foundation

protocol Test {

}

protocol ArrayTest {
    associatedtype E : Test
}

extension Array : ArrayTest where Element:Test{
    typealias E = Element
}

class BBB {
 func ggg<T:ArrayTest>( kk: ((_ value:T) -> Void)?){

 }
}

class AAA<T:ArrayTest> {

    func ggg(){
     BBB().ggg { (test) in//Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred 
 here

     }
 }
 }
```

Comment: What type do you want `test` to be in the line `BBB().ggg { (test) in`?

Comment: An array with element is Test type

Comment: Sometimes it still seems the compiler is not as clever as we are, so you need to explicitly annotate the type: `BBB().ggg { (test:T) in // ...`

Comment: Better naming (using "real world" names, not `ggg` and `kk`, etc ), and explaining what you're trying to achieve would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just do `BBB().ggg { (test: [Test]) in ...` because `[Test]` does not conform to `ArrayTest`.

This might come as surprising to you, as you wrote:

```
extension Array : ArrayTest where Element: Test{
    typealias E = Element
}
```

Surely the above extension applies to `[Test]`, right? No. For the above extension to apply, `Element` must conform to `Test`, but [`Test` does not conform to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself).

I think what you might mean is this:

```
class AAA<T:ArrayTest> {

    func ggg(){
        BBB().ggg { (test: T) in

        }
    }
}
```

This uses `T` from the declaration of `AAA`.

And as the user of the `AAA` class, you need to pass an actual type that conforms to `ArrayTest`, such as `[U]`, where `U` is a type conforming to `Test`.

Comment: It works!,Thank you very much.this help me a lot,But i still need to understand for a while

Comment: @Dandelion please consider accepting my answer if you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can't define a type of generic parameter `T`. You need to specify the type of `T` explicitly:

```
BBB()ggg { (test: [Test]) in

}
```